# SQS sendMessage not completing properly - even using await

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We've got an occasional weird problem in our AWS lambda function where `sendMessage()` only gets completed in the /next/ function invocation. Our code looks like:

```
await sqsClient.sendMessage(params).promise()
```

As you can see, we're awaiting on the promise... but occasionally it looks like the promise doesn't get completed until the next lambda invocation comes into the same warm container.

Any theories on what might cause that?

Comment: Gotta see the Lambda function handler!

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of debugging, I eventually tracked it down to us having a line of code in our codebase that called `context.done()` but then letting code continue to execute.

The next time our code calls `await ...`, I assume that node's async handling kicks in, realises that it is marked as done, so then just abruptly ends the lambda execution... even though the promise hasn't yet completed.